# Error in discord.py : TypeError: unexpected keyword argument(s) ['Bot']

Tags: discord.py

I got an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\AS-TEAM\cp\public\hello.py", line 22, in <module>
    bot.run("thisistokensorry:(", Bot=False)
  File "E:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run   
    return future.result()
  File "E:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 663, in start
    raise TypeError("unexpected keyword argument(s) %s" % list(kwargs.keys()))
TypeError: unexpected keyword argument(s) ['Bot']
```

So, how do I **fix** it?
The python code is:

```py
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.content.find("!Hello") != -1:
        await message.channel.send('Hi')
    if message.content.lower().startswith('message everyone'):
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            await time.sleep(.25)
            members = guild.members
            for member in members:
                if member.bot is True:
                    continue
                await time.sleep(.25)
                channel = await member.create_dm()
                await channel.send('sup')

bot.run("thisistokensorry:(", Bot=False)
```

And, I need help with it. because I want it fixed for the first time!
**please fix it**

Comment: What does it mean `Bot=False`? According to your `Traceback` the most recent error is raised at line 22.

Comment: You should also regenerate your token, since in your first code snippet you put `OTE3MDEwODg4NDYzMTAxOTcy.YbYDRg.mQBQUp0xetLY1q-unG8MmsOTcgs` copy-pasting the Traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `bot=False` instead of `Bot=False` because it's valid name of  kwarg.